# C++ Arduino - Random Function doesn't work

Tags: c++, random, arduino

Hi C++ Devs and StackOverflow users!

The code following is what I did, but some reason, random function doesn't work, or output for a result always the same value which is '1', did I do anything wrong? How should I fix this issue?

```
  void setup()           
  {
  int randNumber;
  int i;

  randNumber = random(2);
  Serial.println(randNumber);
  pinMode(PIEZO, OUTPUT);
  delay(3000);

  if (randNumber == 0)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < 105; i++)                                       
    {
      tone(PIEZO, notes[i], time[i]);                                
      delay(time[i]);
    }
  }
  else if (randNumber == 1)                                     
    for (i = 0; i < 116; i++)                                       
    {
      tone(PIEZO, Snowman_Notes[i], Snowman_Rhythm[i]);                                  
      delay(Snowman_Rhythm[i]);
    }
}
void loop()                                                      
{
}
```

Comment: Did you `randomSeed(analogRead(0));` before using `random`?

Comment: Nope, I didn't... Do I have to type randomSeed(analogRead(0)); before using the random function? I will try that! :) Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes, the `analogRead` should be from an un-connected pin so you get random noise to seed the generator.

Comment: @super Thanks a lot for your help, your explanation makes sense! I fixed my source code, and random function works fine! :)  Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to seed random first. Use `randomSeed(seed)`.

Before using any PRNG (pseudo random number generator), you have to seed the generator. The seed should be different every time otherwise you'll get the same sequence over and over. That is, if you call `randomSeed(2);` and then call `random()`, you'll get the same numbers in the same order every time. The pattern of numbers are the same for a given seed. As mentioned in the comments, only seed ONCE per program

So, you'll want to seed the PRNG with a different number every time. Taken from the [website](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/randomseed/), you can just used `randomSeed( analogRead(pinNum) );`, where pinNum should be an unconnected pin.

Comment: I highly appreciated to your detailed explanation, I added that randomSeed( analogRead(pinNum)); line in my code, and it works like a charm! Merry Christmas and Happy New Year!